# Power factor improvement

Tags: voltage, capacitor, energy

There are 3 resistive bulbs (60 watts each) in series fed by 230Vrms from the transformer.

If I apply capacitors in parallel with load I will get more Voltage. The more capacitors, the higher the voltage, and the bulbs glow more. If I remove all the bulbs and leave the capacitors, I will get an output voltage which will be more than the input voltage.

If we can increase voltage just applying capacitors in parallel, why do we use huge generators like dams to generate 66kV, when we could just generate a few volts and then use capacitors to increase the voltage to 66kV?
In these pictures this man add capacitors to increase the voltage across bulbs and then he removed bulb one by one and the voltage across the load is more than the input voltage
In this way how much voltage I can increase just by applying more and more capacitors

[image: Some kind of electrical experiment. A lightbulb appears to be powered via a transformer from a wall socket. There is also some measuring equipment][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Please add a circuit diagram to show exactly what you mean about the circuit with the bulbs.

Comment: Seems   confused  AC,DC?

Comment: Why do you think it consumes energy to create 66 kV? Transformers are very efficient.

Comment: In this picture there is only one bulb and just besides the bulb 3 or 4 capacitors are connected in parallel

Comment: Lots of money spend to create 66kv

Comment: My question is why we are making 66kv or more even we can increase voltage just by applying capacitor in parallel

Comment: Did you wire the transformer in series like an inductor? . Is it a large microwave oven Cap? then you are just using resonance to boost voltage not real power.

Comment: I have changed your question a lot because I almost could not understand it. I hope this is okay with you. If this is not okay with you, you may change it back.

Comment: Did he measure the input *current*?

Comment: Since nobody else has said it... it is impossible to output 16 times more *power* than goes into the transformer. The *voltage* may increase due to resonance, but the *power* will still be limited exactly the same. If it were a 1kVA transformer, you cannot get 16kVA out of it through resonance.

Comment: rdtsc I m getting more power see the brightness of the and voltage increasing and increasing

Answer (score 6):

You've discovered a resonating 2nd order low pass filter. OK, it's not a new electronic discovery of course but it might be for you.

Series inductance from the power source (it looks like you have a big inductive component) and parallel capacitance can boost the AC voltage at the resonant frequency of the supply. More load current reduces the Q of the circuit but you can get pretty reasonable voltage increases.

[image]

The above on-line simulation can be [found here](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RLC%20LPF.html#RLC_low_pass_filter_type_2). At 50 Hz, the voltage has magnified nearly 16 times but you can get reasonable and modest voltage improvements with smaller value components.

The above simulation shows a 100,000 uH inductor (100 mH) in series with the supply feeding a 100,000 nF capacitor (100 uF) and a load of 500 ohms.

See how the resonance peaks at 50.32 Hz (I couldn't be bothered to make it exactly 50 Hz)? So, if you  had 230 volts AC directly across a 500 ohm resistor you'd get a power of 106 watts. With the circuit above with 24 dB of voltage gain at 50 Hz you'll dissipate nearly 27 kW in the 500 ohm load.

> I*f we can increase voltage just applying capacitors in parallel, why
> do we use huge generators*

The problem with using capacitors is that the resulting supply voltage is quite load dependent whereas using a proper generator and transformers, the resulting voltage is stabler against variable load conditions.

Comment: Andy aka I m not talking about the resonance in which the resistance gets the maximum power I am talking about how much voltage I can increase just by applying capacitor across the series of resistive load because the frequency is fixed which is 50hz and if I can increase lots of voltage or the voltage which is higher than the input voltage then from where I m getting the power and in this way I can make from small amount of voltage to a high amount of voltage

Comment: You are actually resonating with the inductance of  your AC voltage supply. You may not be perfectly resonating because the inductance may be quite small but you will increase the voltage supplied to the load (as per the addition to my answer). This type of circuit doesn't steal power from anywhere other than the supply. Your question title is "power factor improvement" and that's what happens in power factor correction - you resonate the AC power.

Comment: Andy aka thank you but how much voltage I can increase by applying a capacitor across the resistor?

Comment: Well, the simulation in my answer increased the voltage by 24 dB and 24 dB is nearly 16 times so, 230 volts would become 3645 volts.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

This simulation assumes you have used the transformer as a large inductor and your hidden caps are like those rated for microwave ovens.
As you see I can choose a resistance like 3 bulbs in series to tune it to 50Hz.

This is a fake question like over-unity power, rather it is just lucky resonance.

Reducing the resistance to 1 bulb will lower the peak to 1/3 and just stores energy to raise voltage at the expense of higher impedance.

Comment: Tony The voltage that is increasing because capacitor is storing energy and fed to the load?

Comment: The voltage gain is because the R load current is much less than the LC current at resonance, roughly by the ratio of impedance Qp=R/2pi*fL